# How to add fixed Prescription charge in Prestashop

Tags: customization, addition, prestashop, cart

How to add fixed Prescription charge in Prestashop

Something similar to 
http://www.vusionglasses.com/58-men-women-eyewear-endis-eyeglass-frames-bold-rectangular.html?id_combination=46

What Vusionglasses is doing is passing additional cost as per prescription and then in controller adding it to the product price.

I'm not able to figure out exactly where should I put my additional price code?

in my site. There are 4 packages and user has to select one and that much additional cost should be added to product while adding it to cart.

Adding this using combinations and inbuilt features is impossible for all products!
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by
1. Creating a customization field for each product while importing.
2. Create a custom form on product page as per requirement.
3. Before adding the product to cart, save the custom form data through Product Customization field.

This will add the customization throughout the shopping process.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code for this solution?